# How to identify implemented code location in open source project binaries?

Tags: cmake, build, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

There is a c code in wireshark [packet-s7comm.c](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/blob/master/epan/dissectors/packet-s7comm.c), after building how i will identify which generated binary is having its implementation ?

Comment: Do you mean you need to detect which executable or library (in CMake project) contains the file `packet-s7comm.c`?

Comment: yeah you got the point.

Answer (score 1):

The `packet-s7comm.c` file should be compiled into the `epan` library, as seen in the CMake code [here](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/blob/master/epan/CMakeLists.txt#L310):

```
add_library(epan
    #Included so that Visual Studio can properly put header files in solution
    ${LIBWIRESHARK_HEADER_FILES}

    ${LIBWIRESHARK_FILES}
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:crypt>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:dfilter>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:dissectors>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:dissectors-corba>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:ftypes>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:version_info>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:wmem>
    $<$<BOOL:${LUA_FOUND}>:$<TARGET_OBJECTS:wslua>>
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/image/libwireshark.rc
)
```

You can't see the `packet-s7comm.c` file included specifically here, because it is contained in the `dissectors` object library target.